# Image background subtraction, resizing, cropping, moving images (python, image processing)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, reshape

I am suhwan kim.
I am a beginner in image processing. Let me ask you a few questions.

1. There are several images of apples. There is only 1 apple in 1 image. How do I move the apples in all images to the center?? For example, if there is an apple in the lower left, the image in the upper right will be cut off.
2. How do I make all images the same size when they are different sizes?
3. In question 2, how do I fix the center of the image and reduce the size of the outside?

4.When taking pictures of the same location 5 minutes before and 5 minutes later, I am trying to find the difference between the two images to check the changes. However, when the position of the image is moved due to a slight movement, what should I do to move it to the original position?

thanks.

Please let me know if you have a similar example

Comment: You can help us further by providing sample images

Comment: please review [ask]. one question per question. focus.